# How to split a list to only use one column

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R, and I can't figure out how to split the list that I'm working with. I have

```
B<-tapply(newdata$lf.d1, newdata$year, mean)
```

But I want to concatenate the mean values onto another matrix without the year values. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Anna It is better to show some reproducible example for others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `tapply` with a single grouping factor will be an R contingency table with rownames. There is only a single column (actually not even that because it is a table object and only has a single dimension unless you coerce it with `as.matrix`). If you want to remove the names, then use the `unname` function.

```
 unname(B)

 unname(as.matrix(B))
```